# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdatper and big amount of images

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter and I want to show a big amount of images with good quality. I have custom FragmentPagerAdapter and I put into it array with paths to images and then i am creating fragment for every image. The problem is in that when I have a lot of images scrolling between ViewPager items becomes too slow. What are the ways to make fast scrolling?

1. Resize images in a separate thread?
2. Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PagerAdapter` override `destroyItem` it works well for huge images:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPhotos.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return obj.equals(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            View imageLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            // set up imageView
            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Shahidul! But i have troubles with removeView method because of items of my adapter that are not views but fragments. And in this case i have this exception  "java.lang.ClassCastException: FragmentImageItem cannot be cast to android.view.View"

Comment: Try this:
`public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
  container.removeView(((Fragment)object).getView());
}`

Comment: Great, now it is working! The speed is  faster, but not fast enough(((((. I have an array with paths to 300 images. In onCreateView method of my FragmentImageItem class i  call BitmapFactory.decodeFile method to get Bitmap for each imageview. And in  getItem method of my custom adapter class i send message into Log and for the first time i have five created items and log messages, and then for each scroll getItem method is called only once, but  image is loading still slow enough((

Comment: I have solved this by rescaling my image BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inSampleSize = 16; Thank you, Shahidul!